# GeoServer: Use oracle as raster store without spatial extension

Tags: raster, geoserver, spatial-database, oracle-spatial

Is it possible to store raster data (e.g. GeoTIFFs) in an oracle table and access it from geoserver without using the oracle spatial extension/GeoRaster? I would store the images as blobs, but I don't find a way to access the rasta data from GeoServer and use it as a DataStore.